# Why is Open Graph Built-In Like not working anymore?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've created a Facebook App and Open Graph Action "Like" for Object (this might be the global like action for any kind of information).

I just want to get this format on Recent Activity, using a simple Like Button: **"USERNAME" likes "OG:TITLE" on APPNAME**

Im using this code:

> > `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="**" />`
> >     `<meta property="og:type"   content="article" />`
> >     `<meta property="og:url"    content="**" />`
> >     `<meta property="og:title"  content="**" />`
> >     `<meta property="og:image"  content="**" />`

And loading the SDK like this:

> > `<script>(function(d, s, id) {
> >                       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
> >                       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
> >                       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
> >                       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*******";
> >                       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
> >                       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
> >
> >                       </script>`

It worked for a day and then stopped and die!

I would like to know if theres any kind of fix for this? What should i do, or what could be wrong?

Thanks to everyone for your time!

Comment: Are you getting any JS error messages?

Comment: Firebug says no! Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript sdk for liking web pages or objects.
Here is sample code.
Note that you should get accesstoken from user via authorization.

```
FB.api(
        '/me/og.like',
        'post',
        { 'object': 'http://www.yourwebpage.com/',
        'access_token': 'aaaa'  },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('you couldnt like.');
           } else {
              alert('you liked it.');
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use FB debugger to test your link is everything correct? 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug